# Kamatz and shva in words with ayin-lamed-mem root in Kaddish

Tags: pronunciation, kaddish

There are several words in the Kaddish with the root "עלם" and a kamatz under the ayin, and a shva under the lamed, such as: בְּעָלְמָא , וּלְעָלְמֵי , עָלְמַיָּא.

My intuition tells me that in each of these words, the kamatz under the ayin is a regular kamatz (**not** kamatz katan), and the shva under the lamed is shva na.

But, I can't explain why it couldn't be a kamatz katan with a sheva nach, following the rule that a kamatz in an unstressed, closed syllable is kamatz katan.

How are these words correctly pronounced and why?

Comment: Those words are in Aramaic, are you sure the standard rules apply? Further, if they came from the word "Olam" then they would actually be a cholam converted to a kamatz, and therefore should be a kamatz katan. Ironically, my intuition says it's a kamatz katan and a shva nach, and it looks like [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371110/jewish/Text-of-the-Mourners-Kaddish.htm)'s version has it that way. Let's see what other people have to answer.

Comment: IIRC Artscroll (at least in some of their siddurim) mark the sheva of the lamed as a sheva na.

Answer (score 4):

When the word עלמא appears (twice) in [Daniel 2:20, Minchas Shai comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.2.20?lang=he&with=Minchat%20Shai&lang2=he) that "in several accurate manuscripts the ע has a maarich (another name for a meseg)," which would mark it as a kamatz gadol.

Comment: This is a good clue, but it leads me to more questions. Is there a definitive source that the עלמא in Kaddish is a quote from Daniel? And, if so, why don't siddurim put a meteg on the ayin?

Comment: @MarcStober It's not a quote, but I think there's a general tendency to use the Aramaic in Tanach as a guide to its correct pronunciation in other contexts. The lack of a meseg - I don't know; for one thing, you'd probably have to look at siddurim that take care with such things, for example Rinat Yisrael. For what it's worth, Al Hatorah (https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Daniel/2.20#e0n6) doesn't put a meseg in the verse either, but still has a kamatz gadol.